# hiding all rows in table except ones containing data from rdropdown

Tags: jquery, html

im trying to hide all rows containing text i get from a drop down using jquery but i just cant get it to work.
this is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=selectedName]').change(function() {
        $('tr').filter(function () {
            return $(this).find('td').filter(function () {
                return $(this).text().indexOf('$('select[name=select2]').val()') == -1;
            }).length;
        }).$(this).parent("tr:first").hide();
    });
});
```

and this is the drop down:

```
$query = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query); ?>
<select name="selectedName" id="userSelected">
    <option value="" disabled selected>user name</option>
    <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line['user_name'];?>">
            <?php echo $line['user_name'];?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

any idea why isn't it working please?

**UPDATE**

this is how i create the table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" ng-controller="tableCtrl" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <thead>
        <th>user name</th>
        <th>script name</th>
        <th>cron format</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(user_id, row) in data | filter:search">
        <tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in row ">
            <td class="userName">{{user(user_id)}}</td>
            <td class="scriptName">{{script(script_id)}}</td>
            <td class="cronFormat"><span contenteditable="true" ng-repeat="l in letters(cron_format) track by $index">{{l}}</span><button class="save"  ng-click="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format)">save</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the result is a table with three columns and dropdown including all user_name

Comment: can you post the table html and an example of what you want to happen?

Comment: ok and you want to hide the rows which contain the selected username is that it?

Comment: yes , hiding rows that in the user name column there is the selected user name from the drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there just need to change a couple things:

- `indexOf('$('select[name=select2]').val()')` has invalid placement of apostrophes;
- `$('select[name=select2]').val()` should be `$('select[name=selectedName]').val()`;
- The last part `.$(this).parent("tr:first").hide();` is invalid but the logic was correct the filter function will return the unwanted rows then you can just hide them;
- `$(this).find('td')` can be changed to `$(this).find('td.userName')` because we only need to search the cell with class "userName".

The end result should be the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=selectedName]').change(function() {
        $('tr').filter(function () {
            return $(this).find('td.userName').filter(function () {
                return $(this).text().indexOf($('select[name=selectedName]').val()) == -1;
            }).length;
        }).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much...wiered problem thoguh...filter only works first time i run it...any idea why?

Comment: That's probably a different question now, post a new one so more people can help you.